# PHP define() function as URL

Tags: php, url, xampp, localhost

I'm developing a website for my conclusion work at school. I'm using *XAMPP v3.2.1*. to localhost the site.

My site's folder's are configured just like this in `htdocs` folder:

- **ibnm**

  - css
  - js
  - img
  - ...
  - **site**

    - about
    - midia
    - ...
    - includes.php
    - **index.php** (HOME PAGE)

My problem starts here: on `index.php` I'm including `includes.php`, that's a simple file with define() functions to the folders of my site so I can print the constant on the HTML tags of the site as URL (just like below)

```
    //includes.php
    <?php
       define("css", "localhost/ibnm/css");
    ?>

    //index.php
    <?php
       include_once("includes.php");
    ?>

    <link href="<?= css; ?>/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But when I do this, the CSS don't function. When I see an `<a>` tag with the previously defined URL on page it looks like

*localhost/ibnm/site/**localhost/ibnm/css***

instead of

***localhost/ibnm/css***

It's confunsing 'cause if the `<a>` tag doesn't have any value (`href=""`) it output *localhost/ibnm/site/*.

What can be wrong? XAMPP or coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the browser think localhost is a folder, and then do this ontop of the current path, to fix is just add `http://` before the localhost

```
define("css", "http://localhost/ibnm/css");
```

Answer (score 3):

Any url is not starts with http then browser will assume that its relative path so it will append to your current path, thats why your getting **localhost/ibnm/site/localhost/ibnm/css**.
And one small correction in your code, its not good idea to hard code server name in the code, better to get server name dynamically. So that you no need to change while deploying your site in real server.

```
//includes.php
    <?php
       define("css",     $host='http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/ibnm/css');
    ?>
```

Comment: I will remember that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using absolute path you can just add one slash before CSS path -

```
<link href="/<?= css; ?>/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```